# Cannot type in terminal window

Tags: windows, terminal, pycharm

I cannot type in the terminal window on PyCharm after updating to windows 10.  This may be a compatibility issue, I am not sure.  Has anyone else encountered this problem on windows 10, and also does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solved it.

Type cmd, and open the properties dialog.
Check the option: "Use legacy console (requires relaunch)".
You just need to close and open a new terminal in pycharm and it works.
By doing this you will lose the caracteristics of the new windows terminal.

Have fun!

Comment: VCS problems were also solved with this adjustments. No need to use windows terminal anymore.  ;)

Comment: I am confused on how to open this properties dialog.  Can you please help?

Comment: Just click windows start menu and then type "cmd". Click on the "c:\" icon on the top left corner button and click properties.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the problem. Also, if anyone else isn't seeing the option  "Use inherited console (restart required)" then look for "Use legacy console (requires relaunch)".

Answer (score 2):

Do this it worked for me. 
Go to tools in the top menu bar and uncheck Vim Emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else has this issue I recommend  using the regular windows terminal for now, or if you just need to run some manage.py tasks then hit Ctrl+Alt+R in PyCharm and use that window instead.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the tools and uncheck the vim emulator. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue I got it working, so posting here so it might help someone.
Go to `File` select `Invalidate caches/Restart` then restart PyCharm.

> Make sure to Disable `vim emulator` in `tools`